# How to cancel a periodic toast with condition

Tags: android

With the code bellow my toast shows up periodically ( i think similar code was found here ). I want my toast appearing every x seconds when w == 0, or else cancel it. The problem is that i am not able to cancel the toast when w ! = 0. The code that I use for periodic toast is:

```
                final Timer timer = new Timer();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();

                if (w == 0.0) {

                    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            t.show();
                        }
                    };

                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500); 
                        }
                    }, 500, 1000);

                   else {  
                    //  ?????
```

inside else statement, i tried timer.cancel , removeCallBacks, even removeCallBacksAndMessages, but nothing worked. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead with something like this:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            t.show();
                        }
                    };
 if (w == 0.0){
  final ScheduledFuture<?> future    =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 500, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 }else{
     scheduler.shutdownNow();
 }
```

**EDIT** 
I tried to replicate what you want to do, and this should work. We put the futures in a List and when the right condition is reached we cancel everything.

```
public class Main {

    static int MAX_COUNT = 6;
    static volatile int  counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ArrayList<ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   System.out.println("Runnuble: "+counter++);
                                }
                            };

         while(true){

             //This avoid counter (and CPU) to go too fast
             try {
                Thread.sleep(1200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             if (counter > MAX_COUNT - 1){
                 // we cancel everything
                 for(ScheduledFuture<?> future : futures)
                     if(!future.isCancelled())
                         future.cancel(true);
                 scheduler.shutdown();
                 break;
             }else{     
                 //we put the future in a list
                 futures.add(scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 500, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
             }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think your answer is great. The only problem now is that I'm getting an error on future variable, "variable 'future' may not have been initialized". It think initialized it to null will be wrong. Plus, if future variable is final, how can i assign a value to it ? ( future = scheduler.scheduleAtFicedRate(.... )

Comment: Try it.. by the way, I've updated the answer. I cannot try it, but if you don't have to reuse the scheduler it should be fine

Comment: Still no working..the toast does not disappear .. i dont know why.

Comment: Try to leave the final to the future variable, initialize the future to null and then instead of scheduler.shutdownNow(), use future.cancel(true) and scheduler.shutdown() (check future!= null)

Comment: When i do this, i get (future != null) is always false !  final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                     ScheduledFuture<?> future = null;
                    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            t.show(); }    };
             if (w == 0.0){  future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);
                  } else {
                        if( future != null)
                            future.cancel(true);  
                            scheduler.shutdown();

Comment: I updated my answer, this, finally, should work. (If I have understood well what you want to do :) )

Comment: thank you for your answer and your time, but unfortunately not working. i want it in my main activity to show toast periodically when (w==0) and cancel it when (w != 0) . we dont need a counter inside the if condition

Comment: Yes, I just stimulated a similar behaviour. So, put some more code of your app, and we'll solve your problem ;)

Comment: i mean we are not checking anywhere for (w==0) and i dont understand what the counter offers in the condition. Please see your facebook messages, i sent you one there

Answer (score 0):

you can use `final List<Float> wList = new ArrayList();` instead of just `foat w` in that case it will be available in inner functions too. So you can edit it by `wList.add(newW);` and get the latest value by `wList.get(wList.size() - 1)`

But it's some kind of hack, so take a look to FMiscia's answer before it :)